# rails update 3.2.5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

for our redmine-installation (=>tool for project planing, ticketing etc.)
we installed ruby on our server, which worked fine ...
But now we need a rails update (Rails 3.2.3) for a redmine update and 
so the troubles began:

I did the following:

1.) installing ruby 1.9.3

```
root@information:~#  rvm install 1.9.3

Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #compiling 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.24 for ruby-1.9.3-p194 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #importing default gemsets (/usr/local/rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #complete 
root@information:~# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
root@information:~#
root@information:/var/www/redmine# rvm docs generate
Currently 'rvm docs ...' does not work with non-rvm rubies.
root@information:/var/www/redmine#
```

2.) updating gem

```
root@information:/var/www/redmine# gem update

Updating installed gems
Updating actionmailer
Successfully installed i18n-0.6.0
Successfully installed multi_json-1.3.6
Successfully installed activesupport-3.2.5
Successfully installed builder-3.0.0
Successfully installed activemodel-3.2.5
Successfully installed rack-1.4.1
Successfully installed rack-cache-1.2
Successfully installed rack-test-0.6.1
Successfully installed journey-1.0.3
Successfully installed hike-1.2.1
Successfully installed tilt-1.3.3
Successfully installed sprockets-2.1.3
Successfully installed erubis-2.7.0
Successfully installed actionpack-3.2.5
Successfully installed mime-types-1.18
Successfully installed polyglot-0.3.3
Successfully installed treetop-1.4.10
Successfully installed mail-2.4.4
Successfully installed actionmailer-3.2.5
Updating activerecord
Successfully installed arel-3.0.2
Successfully installed activerecord-3.2.5
Updating activeresource
Successfully installed activeresource-3.2.5
Updating bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.1.4
Updating fastercsv
Successfully installed fastercsv-1.5.5
Updating rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!

Successfully installed rack-ssl-1.3.2
Successfully installed thor-0.15.2
Successfully installed json-1.7.3
Successfully installed rdoc-3.12
Successfully installed railties-3.2.5
Successfully installed rails-3.2.5

Gems updated: i18n, multi_json, activesupport, builder, activemodel, rack, rack-cache, rack-test, journey, hike, tilt, sprockets, erubis, actionpack, mime-types, polyglot, treetop, mail, actionmailer, arel, activerecord, activeresource, bundler, fastercsv, rack-ssl, thor, json, rdoc, railties, rails


root@information:/var/www/redmine#
```

3.) trying to update rails

```
root@information:/var/www/redmine# gem install rails --version '~> 3.2.0'

Successfully installed rails-3.2.5

1 gem installed

Installing ri documentation for rails-3.2.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.5...
root@information:/var/www/redmine# rails -v

Rails 2.3.5

root@information:/var/www/redmine#
```

My problem is, that redmine 2.0.1 had problems with ruby 1.9.3
and so tried to downgrade ruby by e.g. "rvm uninstall 1.9.3" and tried
to reinstall ruby 1.8.6...

After all I just upgraded to ruby 1.9.3 but failed to upgrade to rails 3.2.5....

Can you help me here ?

I'm new to ruby. Did I forget installation steps?.
Thanks in advance for your help?
Cheers,

Ansgar

Comment: Why are you installing Ruby 1.9.3 in order to upgrade Rails? Is Redmine compatible with 1.9.2 or 1.8.7? Either of those would be better than 1.8.6.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby upgrades will not, in general, disturb your database. So, first step is to backup your database. Rails upgrades will often disturb your database once you have a clean install, since often you will have to do a "rake db:migrate" at the end.

There are a number of steps to upgrading the complete stack:ruby, rails, then redmine. You will need to read this document, which will guide you step by step through the upgrade:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade

Comment: Hi David,

that was really quick and targeted help....Thank you!
But although "rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production --trace"
runs succesfully , "rails -v" still delivers "Rails 2.3.14".
if I run "rake db:migrate --trace" it ends up witt "Unknown database 'redmine_development"
Before I had to downgrade rake by "gem install rake --version 0.8.7"
and to exchange "RbConfig" for "Config" in alt_system.rb" &  rake.rb

So I need Help again...

Regards,

Ansgar